How to get/read moved file name in Jmeter from OS Process Sampler response
Vis OS Process Sampler in Jmeter. I am renaming one file with epoch and then moving that file to another location.
Operating system: Windows 10
tool to perform operations: PowerShell
i.e. TestFile.docx to TestFile_2008202416202205.docx
I want name of that file to upload it somewhere via jmeter HTTP request which requires file name as a parameter.
how can I take name of that file?
In response of OS Process sampler of Rename doesn't return anything but we are passing TestFile-${__time(,)}.docx in request parameter, any way to get that name?

If you change this:
TestFile-${__time(,)}.docx

to this:
TestFile-${__time(,postfix)}.docx

you will be able to access the value generated by the __time() function as ${postfix} JMeter Variable like:
TestFile-${postfix}.docx

More information: Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction

when I tried TestFile-${postfix}.docx it mismatches time stamp and its going to find that mismatched file in the directory and fails my request. do we have any other solution?
